# Shortcuts Tab in Outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

What exactly is **Shortcuts** tab in Office 365? And what is the use of it? I am not looking for `keyboard shortcuts`.

[image]

I even searched on Outlook's own `Tell me what you want to do` search feature. And it also shows all keyboard shortcuts results. (Which is kind of dumb, that they don't have a reasonable help up front.)

Sorry, if this is a duplicate. I searched here, but also found mostly questions related to keyboard shortcuts in Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your own custom menu in the Shortcuts Navigation. It can consist of anything like shortcuts to Outlook folders, Explorer Folder, files and applications and can be organized in expandable/collapsible groups.

- For an Outlook folder; click Add new Shortcut
- For an Explorer folder or file; drag & drop the folder or file on the group name from an Explorer window

Reference: [Navigation Pane Tips & Tricks](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/navigationpane.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that you can drag your explorer folders too. Only issue is that when I open folder from `Shortcuts` tab, Microsoft Outlook Security Notice comes up - `Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern`. This is kind of silly, that I get this message every time I open a local folder shortcut! Any way to disable this annoying message?